# Polymer Registration Form

Tags: php, mysql, polymer-1.0

i'll get to the point, i'm fairly new at using polymer and i want to make a registration form that pushes data to php and to a Mysql server,however from what i understand you need to use iron-forms or ajax-form,which i dont fully understand.
this deals with form submission and not verification
the following is my code help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<paper-card>
          <h4 align="center">Sign Up</h4>
          <div id="Sign-Up">

            <template is="dom-bind" id="expand-demo">
          <paper-icon-button
              icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-down"
              title="more info"
              on-tap="_toggleMoreInfo"
              style="float: right;">
          </paper-icon-button>
          <iron-collapse id="more-info">

          <form is="ajax-form" method="post" action="sign_up_connect.php" >
          <paper-input decorator label="First Name">
            <input id="firstName"  name="firstName">
          </paper-input>
          <paper-input decorator label="Last Name" >
            <input id="lastName"  name="lastName">
          </paper-input>
          <paper-input label="E-mail Address" id="email"></paper-input>

          <paper-input type="password"  label="Password" id="pass"></paper-input>
          <paper-input type="password"  label="Re-type Password"></paper-input>
          <paper-input type="number" max="70" min ="18"  label="Age" id="age"></paper-input>
          <p>Sex</p>
          <paper-radio-group selected="">
            <paper-radio-button name="Male">Male</paper-radio-button>
            <paper-radio-button name="Female">Female</paper-radio-button>
          </paper-radio-group>


          <paper-button raised id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up" class="colorful" onclick="clickHandler(event)">Sign Up</paper-button>
          </iron-collapse>
          </template>
          </form>

          </div>
        </paper-card>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Registration verification and authentication by ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501643/registration-verification-and-authentication-by-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iron-form can be observed via listeners.
Keep in mind that the iron-form element is ajax-based (It will not reload the page), so you have to check yourself for its reponse / error in your element listeners. See http://jsbin.com/wefavu/edit?html,output

Comment: hi thank you for your reply this is my JSBin https://jsbin.com/nonuwo/edit?html,output please note no changes have been made and second login and sign up were for testing purposes thank you

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply i have managed to setup iron-form to send data to php but thats as far as ive gotten https://jsbin.com/cisipi/1/edit?html,output  however i remain stuck on what to do next ie. input validation from php iron-form response and ajax, and mainly how to redirect if user is valid

Comment: @AhmedBakir I think your example is way too complex and might seem intimidating / messy. I suggest that you set up a Polymer-ready jsbin with only a minimal subset of what you want. Pay attention to indentation, and i'm sure people (Including myself) will be happy to solve this issue...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i have narrowed the code down to the login form only, yes i am still using iron form since it seems to work until i completely figure out iron ajax, https://jsbin.com/yunagi/edit?html,output sorry if it doesn't display as  it should thank you

Comment: Would that be an acceptable solution for you? http://jsbin.com/wefavu/edit?html,output

Comment: yes it does help me get through iron response, i would like to ask if i can set the response function to open another page if result is true, again thank you very much

Comment: it doesn't seem to be passing data to the php file, eg in sign up it creates a blank user field

Comment: The solution i've proposed posts data correctly. Use a requestbin if you want to understand how to read the data on the server-side, or on your server simply output the whole payload body to your console.

Opening a new page when the response is true should be another question. Your initial question was to understand how to set up the iron-form component.

Comment: oddly it works fine on firefox but on on chrome it acts strange, lastly i'd like to know what i should have as a response from php side  this is how i'm currently checking users on login https://jsbin.com/hecoru/edit?html,output  i am not entirely sure of how i should send a xhr response back thanks

Comment: The client is asking for JSON as a response, but your server-side code is answering with something completelly different.

Comment: yes i had set it to {{"success:1"}} as a response before can you give me a example of how it should respond

Comment: It should probably be set to '{"success":true}'. '{{"success:1"}}' isn't JSON at all.

Comment: I just tried the JSBin against a RequestBin (Go to http://requestb.in, setup a new bin, and change the "action" attribute of the iron-form to point to it (Eg http://requestb.in/1jqzvhv1). Run the test, and then go inspect your request bin (Eg http://requestb.in/1jqzvhv1?inspect), you'll see that the form is correctly posting the data. The fact that it's not working with Firefox is because of the <base> not being supported, and therefore Polymer cannot load. It's an issue with the JSBin, not with Polymer.

Comment: it manages to post successfully in firefox http://requestb.in/17oeqp41?inspect  but not in google chrome i have tried setting responses as echo json_encode (); and just normal echo but both still respond with null

Comment: thanks a lot @doodloo managed to get responses using json_encode now to find a way to redirect pages :D

Comment: Why redirect? You could instead use iron-pages to change page and not refresh the browser. You might want to ask another question about this.